# CSS selector for variable, unknown number of "nested" elements

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I'm trying to change the properties of all elements of a certain kind (in the example, `<p>`) except those that are a direct child of any element with a specific class (in the example, `test`), by using the `:not()` selector.

My problem is that I cannot get this to work when each of the `<p>` elements are nested in differing numbers of elements, as in the example.

My issue essentially boils down to the wildcard in the following line:

```
body * :not(.test) p {
```

It seems as though I need a wildcard that not only represents one random element, but an unknown number of random elements. Does any such thing exist in CSS? (Note that I'm not able to edit the HTML in my actual circumstances, or anything besides the CSS)

**[JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/K3693/3909/)** (`Foo` should remain black)

```css
body * :not(.test) p {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>
    <tr>
      <span class="test">
        <p>Foo</p>
      </span>
    </tr>
    <div>
      <tr>
        <li>
          <p>Bar</p>
        </li>
      </tr>
    </div>
    <p>FooBar</p>
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: That nesting is invalid HTML which will not be matched by any css selector, unless it's created after the DOM has been parsed. But if you're creating that, then please don't. Use `<tr>` elements appropriately, and create valid HTML.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm trying to change the properties of all elements of a certain kind (in the example, `<p>`) except those that are a direct child of any element with a specific class (in the example, `.test`), by using the `:not()` selector.

Since you're talking about the *direct child*, all you need to add is the *child combinator* (`>`):

```
body * :not(.test) > p
```

You're using a *descendant combinator* in your original code:

```
body * :not(.test) p
```

This will not work to keep the `p` child of `.test` black because the `p` is also a descendant of other (non-excluded) elements, such as the `tr` and `body`. So the `:not(.test)` attempt fails because it covers only one of several matching possibilities.

When you switch from descendants to just children, however, the possibilities narrow to, in this case, just one match.